# The bug in rock, paper, scissor game

Tags: python

hi i did a game but its not work well. I couldnt find why. when i press y for continue the game player 2 gains point. Than the loop
isn't start again. İf i choose "y" yrogram asking "Do you want to play
again? (y/n):" forever. but "n" working good.
I started to programing 5 days ago and all code lokking true for me. Please help me. (SORY FOR BAD ENGLISH)
Here my codes

```
<print("""************************
welcome to my game.
Lucky one win.
Have fun.
************************""")

player1 = input("Player 1: Choose one (rock, paper, scissor): ")
player2 = input("Player 2: choose one (rock, paper, scissor): ")
print("Player1 = {}\nPlayer 2 = {}".format(player1, player2))
player1skor, player2skor = 0, 0
while True:

    if player2 == player1:
        print("Draw")

    elif player1 == "rock" and player2 == "scissor":
        print("Rock break to scissor.\nPlayer 1 win")
        player1skor += 1
        print("player1: {}\nplayer2: {}".format(player1skor, player2skor))

    elif player1 == "rock" and player2 == "paper":
        print("Paper wraps the stone.\nPlayer 2 win")
        player2skor += 1
        print("player1: {}\nplayer2: {}".format(player1skor, player2skor))

    elif player1 == "paper" and player2 == "rock":
        print("Paper wraps the stone.\nPlayer 1 win")
        player1skor += 1
        print("player1: {}\nplayer2: {}".format(player1skor, player2skor))

    elif player1 == "paper" and player2 == "scissor":
        print("Scissor cut to paper.\nPlayer2 win")
        player2skor += 1
        print("player1: {}\nplayer2: {}".format(player1skor, player2skor))

    elif player1 == "scissor" and player2 == "paper":
        print("Scissor cut to paper.\nPlayer1 win")
        player1skor += 1
        print("player1: {}\nplayer2: {}".format(player1skor, player2skor))

    elif player1 == "scissor" and player2 == "rock":
        print("Rock break to scissor.\nPlayer2 win")
        player2skor += 1
        print("player1: {}\nplayer2: {}".format(player1skor, player2skor))


    buton = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n): ")

    if buton == "n":
        if player1skor == player2skor:
            print("Draw.")
        elif player1skor > player2skor:
            print("player1 win")
        elif player1skor < player2skor:
            print("player2 win")
            print("player1: {}\nplayer2: {}".format(player1skor, player2skor))
        break
    else:
        continue
```

<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to move the `while True` outside the choice.

```
while True:
    player1 = input("Player 1: Choose one (rock, paper, scissor): ")
    player2 = input("Player 2: choose one (rock, paper, scissor): ")
    print("Player1 = {}\nPlayer 2 = {}".format(player1, player2))
    player1skor, player2skor = 0, 0

    if player2 == player1:
        print("Draw")
```

This is so your entering the choices again instead of reusing the previous answers.

Comment: thank you so much :D it worked. That was so simple mistake but i could not see.